# Subscription onConnect return value not appended to context

Tags: typegraphql

I am using type-graphql to create a GraphQL endpoint, which also defines a subscription. In subscription I am returning an object that contains currentUser property. This is how I am creating the server:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({ schema, context: (ctx) => {
            if(ctx.connection) {
                console.log(`Inside Connection`);
                //console.log(ctx.connection.context); - I can see currentUser property with an actual user
                let obj = {
                    req: ctx.req,
                    currentUser: ctx.connection.context.currentUser
                };
                console.log(obj);
                return obj;
            }
            return {
                req: ctx.req
            }
        },
        subscriptions: {
            path: "/subscriptions",
            onConnect: async (connectionParams: any) => {
                const token = connectionParams["X-JWT"];
                if(token) {
                    const user = await decodeJWT(token);
                    if(user) {
                        return {
                            currentUser: user
                        }
                    }
                }
                throw new Error("Not Authorised to Subscribe...");
            },
            onDisconnect: () => {
                console.log("Client disconnected from subscriptions");
            }
        } 
    });
```

When I create a resolver and print the context there I am unable to see currentUser property in the context.

```
@Resolver()
export class UserResolver {
    @Query(_returns => String)
    async returnHello(@Arg("name") name: string, @Ctx() _ctx: any){
      // console.log("connection")
      console.log(_ctx); // Unable to get currentUser property here
      return `Hello ${name}`;
    };
}
```

I followed the [link](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/1597) and implemented the code in similar way. But still I am not getting currentUser Property in context of Resolver.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it. Thanks to `linus:alpine-edge` from discord. Helped clear my understanding. As the Query is sent over http and subscriptions are sent over websocket, in a query we can never access the context of a subscription. But in a subscription we can access the context object. Below is the subscription:

```
import { User } from "../entities/User";
import { Subscription, Resolver, Root } from "type-graphql";

    @Resolver()
    export class DriversSubscription {
        @Subscription(() => User, {
            topics: "driverUpdate",
            filter: ({ context }) => { 
                console.log(context); // I can see currentUser property
                return true; 
            },
        })
        async driverUpdate(@Root() payload: User): Promise<User> {
            return payload;
        }
    }
```